How to make keyboard virtual using THREE JS in VR?
I'm working on a VR project using THREE.js and I want to create a virtual keyboard that users can interact with inside the VR environment. I've tried several approaches, including creating panels and buttons, but I'm struggling to get it to work correctly.
Here's what I've attempted so far:
Panel and Button Setup: I created a panel for the keyboard base and then added buttons as individual PlaneGeometry meshes. I positioned them correctly on the panel and tried to render text on each button using TextGeometry.
Font Loading: I used the FontLoader from THREE.js to load a font for the button labels. However, I'm facing issues with positioning and scaling the text correctly on each button.
Interactivity: I'm not sure how to make the buttons interactable, i.e., how to detect when a button is "pressed" by the user in VR.
Here's a simplified version of the code I'm working with:
import { System } from 'three/addons/libs/ecsy.module.js';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { Panel } from '../components/Panel.js';
import { FontLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js';
import { TextGeometry } from 'three/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry.js';

export class PanelSystem extends System {
  init({ panel }) {
    this.panel = panel;

    this.panelGroup = new THREE.Group();
    if (this.panel.length > 0 && this.panel[0].scene) {
      this.panel[0].scene.add(this.panelGroup);
    }

    this.panelMeshes = [];
    this.createPanel();
    this.createKeyboard();
  }

  execute() {
    if (this.panel.length > 0) {
      this.panelGroup.rotation.set(
        this.rotation.x * (Math.PI / 180),
        this.rotation.y * (Math.PI / 180),
        this.rotation.z * (Math.PI / 180)
      );
    }

    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }

  createPanel() {
    let panel, xOffset;

    this.panel.forEach(p => {
      this.font = p.font !== undefined ? p.font : Panel.schema.font.default;
      this.layers = p.layers !== undefined ? p.layers : Panel.schema.layers.default;
      this.width = p.width !== undefined ? p.width : Panel.schema.width.default;
      this.height = p.height !== undefined ? p.height : Panel.schema.height.default;
      this.color = p.color !== undefined ? p.color : Panel.schema.color.default;
      this.scene = p.scene || this.scene;
      this.renderer = p.renderer || this.renderer;
      this.camera = p.camera || this.camera;
      this.isSide = p.isSide !== undefined ? p.isSide : Panel.schema.isSide.default;
      this.padding = p.padding !== undefined ? p.padding : Panel.schema.padding.default;
      this.position = p.position || Panel.schema.position.default;
      this.rotation = p.rotation || Panel.schema.rotation.default;

    });

    for (let i = 0; i < this.layers; i++) {
      const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(this.width, this.height);
      const side = this.isSide === true ? THREE.DoubleSide : THREE.FrontSide;
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: this.color, side: side });

      panel = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      if (i === 0) {
        xOffset = 0;
        panel.position.set(this.position.x + xOffset, this.position.y, this.position.z - 0.08);
      } else {
        if (i % 2 !== 0) {
          xOffset = - (this.width + this.padding);
          panel.rotation.set(0, (15 * (Math.PI / 180)), 0);
          panel.position.set(this.position.x + xOffset, this.position.y, this.position.z);
        } else {
          xOffset = (this.width + this.padding);
          panel.rotation.set(0, -(15 * (Math.PI / 180)), 0);
          panel.position.set(this.position.x + xOffset, this.position.y, this.position.z);
        }
      }

      this.panelGroup.add(panel);
      this.panelMeshes.push(
        {
          panel,
          scene: this.scene,
          camera: this.camera,
          renderer: this.renderer
        }
      );
    }
  }

  createKeyboard() {

    // keyboard base
    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 0.3);
    const side = this.isSide === true ? THREE.DoubleSide : THREE.FrontSide;
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: this.color, side: side });

    this.keyboard = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.keyboard.position.set(this.position.x, this.position.y - 0.3, this.position.z + 0.1); // Posisi relatif terhadap panel
    this.keyboard.rotation.set(15, 0, 0);
    this.panelGroup.add(this.keyboard);

    const loader = new FontLoader();
    loader.load('/fonts/Roboto_Italic.json', (font) => {
      fetch(this.font)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          data.keyboard.forEach(row => {
            this.createButton(row, font)
          })
        }).catch(error => console.error('Error fetching JSON:', error))
    })

  }

  createButton(keyboard, font) {
    const xStart = -0.4375; // Minimum x position
    const yStart = -0.1; // Maximum y position
    const xSpacing = 0.1; // Horizontal spacing between keys
    const ySpacing = -0.1; // Vertical spacing between rows

    let currentY = yStart;
    let currentX = xStart;

    keyboard.keys.forEach((key, index) => {
      const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(0.1, 0.1);
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
      const button = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      if (index === 0) {
        currentX = xStart; // Reset x position for each row
      } else {
        currentX += xSpacing;
      }
      button.position.set(currentX, currentY, 0);
      this.keyboard.add(button);

      const textGeometry = new TextGeometry(key, {
        font: font,
        size: 0.05,
        height: 0.01
      });
      const textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000 });
      const textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, textMaterial);
      textMesh.position.set(currentX - 0.045, currentY - 0.03, 0.01);
      this.keyboard.add(textMesh);
    });
    currentY += ySpacing;
  }

}

PanelSystem.queries = {
  panel: { components: [Panel] }
};

my expecting is have a good keyboard, looks like a normal keyboard,
